# how to add filters/conditions when use embedding vectors in opensearch?

Tags: vector, filter, range, embedding, opensearch

I am learning use embedding vectors in opensearch recently. Here is my code:

```
class SpacyEmbeddings(Embeddings):

    def __init__(self, model_name: str = "en_core_web_lg"):
        self.nlp = spacy.load(model_name)

    def embed_documents(self, texts: List[str]) -> List[List[float]]:
        return [self.nlp(text).vector for text in texts]

        return self.nlp(text).vector

embeddings = SpacyEmbeddings()

loader = CSVLoader(file_path="4F947281_tweak1_2020-01-01.csv", 
               metadata_columns=('BUSINESS_ID', 'DATEOCCURRED', 'AMOUNT','ALLOCATED_ACCOUNT_NAME','PREDICTION_ACCOUNT_CATEGORY'))
documents = loader.load()

from langchain.vectorstores import OpenSearchVectorSearch

vectorstore = OpenSearchVectorSearch.from_documents(
     documents,
     embeddings,
     opensearch_url="xxx",
    http_auth=('xxx', 'xxx'),
    timeout = 600,
    index_name=index_name,
    engine="faiss",
    bulk_size=1000
)

docsearch = OpenSearchVectorSearch(
    index_name=index_name,
    embedding_function=embeddings,
    opensearch_url="xxx",
    http_auth=('xxx', 'xxx'),
    timeout=300,
)

returned_docs = docsearch.similarity_search_with_score(
        query='abc defg hi jkl m nop q', 
        k=20,
        search_type="script_scoring",
        space_type="cosinesimil"
    )

returned_docs
```

This is just the basic searching using embedding vectors. Now I want to add some conditions here:

1. give a specific date, just return the data after the specific date.
2. if i have a business_id=abcd, then i just want to have the data belonging to this business_id.

I know how to do the above conditions when doing text search, but how to do it when using embedding vectors?